# How to insert an array to an array

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I would like to add an array to within an existing array.
I am tryin to use array_push which works as long as i dont try to assign a key to the array (if i try to add a key i get a syntax error... :-()

This is my initial array:

```
$ResultArray = array(
    "TransactionDate" => "$TransactionDate",  
    "tx"=>array(
        "0"=>array(
            "TxIndex" => "$TxIndex", 
            "value" => "$Value",  
            "PaymentConfirmedCount" => "$PaymentConfirmedCount"
        ),
        "1"=>array(
            "TxIndex" => "$TxIndex", 
            "value" => "$Value",  
            "PaymentConfirmedCount" => "$PaymentConfirmedCount"
        )
     ) 
 );
```

i would then like to add:

```
$ArrayTOAdd = array(
    "0"=>array(
        "TxIndex" => "$TxIndex", 
        "value" => "$Value",  
        "PaymentConfirmedCount" => 
        "$PaymentConfirmedCount"
    )
);
```

if I try:

```
array_push($ResultArray->tx, $ArrayTOAdd);
```

BUT this does not work and results in a warning of "array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array"

if i try this :

```
array_push($ResultArray, $ArrayTOAdd);
```

it just adds the array but not to $ResultArray->tx

Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to access the element in the array with `$ResultArray["tx"]` and not `$ResultArray->tx`. The second one is for the access to members in a php class. So an

```
array_push($ResultArray["tx"], $ArrayTOAdd);
```

should work.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (i was converting the arrays to objects)
This seems to work now '$ResultArray = (object)array("TransactionDate" => "$TransactionDate",  "tx"=>array((object)array("TxIndex" => "$TxIndex", "value" => "$Value",  "PaymentConfirmedCount" => "$PaymentConfirmedCount"),(object)array("TxIndex" => "$TxIndex", "value" => "$Value",  "PaymentConfirmedCount" => "$PaymentConfirmedCount")) );
$ArrayTOAdd = (object)array("TxIndex" => "$TxIndex", "value" => "$Value",  "PaymentConfirmedCount" => "$PaymentConfirmedCount");
array_push($ResultArray->tx, $ArrayTOAdd);'

Comment: sorry for the messy comment and original post!